# AWS Appsync enhanced subscription filtering not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver, appsync-subscription

AWS [enhanced subscription filtering feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-enhanced-filtering.html) documentation recommends to add the following response mapping template:

```
## Response Mapping Template - onSpecialTicketCreated subscription

$extensions.setSubscriptionFilter($util.transform.toSubscriptionFilter($util.parseJson($ctx.args.filter)))

$util.toJson($context.result)
```

When using a simple request mapping template the subscription will not return any data:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does not mention the following (got it though one month of back and forth with support):

In the request template the payload must be set:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": {}
}
```

If you have fieldLevel resolver note that for some reason they are executed when the subscription is set up and a payload is set. To accommodate this make sure they handle that i.e. event.source.id is not defined. For them to work pass the args as payload:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": $util.toJson($ctx.args)
}
```

Using this frontend side filters like `{"filter" : "{\"severity\":{\"le\":2}}"}` will work again